# File with Control-m characters

Tags: linux

we are working on windows machine and code is deployed in linux.

Some how while developing some linux scripts we have some ctrl-m character. release is provided to customer.

what can be the impact on ctrl-m characters in shell scripts.

nus

Comment: Not sure about the _impact_, but those are `\n` characters which are used in windows, but not linux. You can use `dos2unix` tools to convert your text/source/script files to windows or linux line break format.

Comment: No, they're not.  They're `\r` characters.  The two are very different, and they have different meanings and functions.  Windows terminates lines with `\r\n` while linux uses just `\n` as the terminator.

Answer (score 11):

open the file in vi editor

press escape and type below on command line in the file.

:%s/^M//g

make sure  ^M  is added by hitting Cntrl key + V + M    then hit enter

it will remove the characters and you can save the file.

Answer (score 5):

It will change the shebang line, so that the interpreter isn't found.

```
$ ./t.sh
bash: ./t.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: In my case control-m is not present in shebang line, but rest of the lines. What will be the impact in case lines except shebang has control-M character..

Answer (score 5):

The `^M` characters are carriage returns.  Windows and DOS terminate lines of text with `CR` (`^M`, or ASCII code 13) followed by `LF` (`^J`, or linefeed, ASCII code 10).  Linux uses just `LF`, so the carriage returns appear as part of the text and are interpreted as such.  That means they'll break scripts.

Most linux distributions come with a utility called [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) pre-installed.  You can use it to convert the end-of-line characters from DOS style to linux style.

Some editors will do the conversion automatically for you; others have options that let you specify which mode to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below syntax too. Since in windows, this Control+v+m will not work , you can use \r instead.

Open the file in binary mode to view the Control-M characters using vim editor with -b option and use the below command to replace the Control-M characters

> %s@\r@@g

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following script to clean up `^M` from files in a directory.

```bash
for file in $(find path/to/your/files -type f); do
  tr -d '\r' <$file >temp.$$ && mv temp.$$ $file
done
```